# Prolog Array Pipe Meaning

Tags: syntax, prolog

Can anybody explain the following code? I know it returns true if X is left of Y but I do not understand the stuff with the pipe, underscore and R. Does it mean all other elements of the array except X and Y?

```
    left(X,Y,[X,Y|_]).
    left(X,Y,[_|R]) :- left(X,Y,R).
```

Comment: It's not an array, it's a list. Have you looked at any Prolog documentation or text book or tutorial? The notation `[X|T]` means `X` is the head of the list, and `T` (a list) is the rest of the list, or its tail. You can have multiples in the head: `[X,Y|T]` means a list whose first two elements are `X` and `Y`, and `T` is the rest of the list. Underscore (`_`) is an anonymous variable. It means you don't care what value might be bound to it, if any.

Comment: Yes list you are right. Yes I have read a Prolog tuturial and documentation. Because I still do not understand it, I ask here ;) You explained the first part, which I explained above. I actually do not understand the second part. `left(X,Y,[_|R]) :- left(X,Y,R).` How can I interpret this? When `R` is the tail (all elements after `X` and `Y`) and `X` is before `Y` is true the what does `left(X,Y,[_|R])` mean?

Comment: That's a bigger question than "what does the piping mean". `left(X, Y, [_|R]) :- left(X, Y, R).` says that *`X` is left of `Y` in the list if `X` is left of `Y` in the tail of the list*. It's the recursive condition. Your original question didn't cover this.

Comment: Still did not get what then the underscore means? I would have expected that then list must always start with X and Y

Comment: Like I said before, `_` is an *anonymous variable*. It is a variable. And *anonymous* means you don't care what it's value is. You can write, `left(X, Y, [X,Y|R]).` and it would function properly in this case, but you would get a *singleton variable* warning since `R` is a variable name that appears to serve no purpose (there is only one reference to it).

Comment: Did my answer given below adequately resolve your questions?

Answer (score 3):

If you are ever unsure about what a term "actually" denotes, you can use **`write_canonical/1`** to obtain its *canonical* representation.

For example:

```
| ?-  write_canonical([X,Y|_]).
'.'(_16,'.'(_17,_18))
```

and also:

```
| ?-  write_canonical([a,b|c]).
'.'(a,'.'(b,c))
```

and in particular:

```
| ?-  write_canonical([a|b]).  
'.'(a,b)
```

This shows you that `[a|b]` **is** the term `'.'(a,b)`, i.e., a term with functor `.` and two arguments.

To reinforce this point:

```
| ?- [a|b] == '.'(a,b).

yes
```

Answer (score 1):

@mat answered the original question posted quite precisely and completely. However, it seems you have a bigger question, asked in the comment, about "What does the predicate definition mean?"

Your predicate, `left(X, Y, L)`, defines a relation between two values, `X` and `Y`, and a list, `L`. This predicate is true (a query succeeds) if `X` is immediately left of `Y` in the list `L`.

There are two ways this can be true. One is that the first two elements in the list are `X` and `Y`. Thus, your first clause reads:

```
left(X, Y, [X,Y|_]).
```

This says that *`X` is immediately left of `Y` in the list `[X,Y|_]`*. Note that we do not care what the tail of the list is, as it's irrelevant in this case, so we use `_`. You could use `R` here (or any other variable name) and write it as `left(X, Y, [X,Y|R]).` and it would function properly. However, you would get a *singleton variable* warning because you used `R` only once without any other references to it. The warning appears since, in some cases, this might mean you have done this by mistake. Also note that `[X,Y|_]` is a list of *at least* two elements, so you can't just leave out `_` and write `[X,Y]` which is a list of *exactly two* elements.

The above clause is not the only case for `X` to be immediately left of `Y` in the list. What if they are not the first two elements in the list? You can include another rule which says that *`X` is immediately left of `Y` in a list if `X` is immediately left of `Y` in the tail of the list*. This, along with the base case above, will cover all the possibilities and gives a complete recursive definition of `left/3`:

```
left(X, Y, [_|R]) :- left(X, Y, R).
```

Here, the list is `[_|R]` and the tail of the list is `R`.

Answer (score 0):

This is about the *pattern matching* and about the execution mechanism of Prolog, which is built around the pattern matching.

Consider this:

```
1 ?- [user].

|: prove(T):- T = left(X,Y,[X,Y|_]).
|: prove(T):- T = left(X,Y,[_|R]), prove( left(X,Y,R) ). 
|: 
|: ^Z
true.
```

Here `prove/1` emulates the Prolog workings  proving a query `T` about your `left/3` predicate.

A query is proven by matching it against a head of a rule, and proving that rule's body under the resulting substitution.

An empty body is considered proven right away, naturally.

`prove(T):- T = left(X,Y,[X,Y|_]).` encodes, "*match* the first rule's head. There's no body, so if the matching has succeeded, we're **done**."

`prove(T):- T = left(X,Y,[_|R]), prove( left(X,Y,R) ).` encodes, "*match* the second rule's head, and if successful, prove its body under the resulting substitution (which is implicit)".

Prolog's unification, `=`, performs the pattern matching whilst instantiating any logical variables found inside the terms being matched, according to what's being matched.

Thus we observe,

```
2 ?- prove( left( a,b,[x,a,b,c])).
true ;
false.

3 ?- prove( left( a,b,[x,a,j,b,c])).
false.

4 ?- prove( left( a,b,[x,a,b,a,b,c])).
true ;
true ;
false.

5 ?- prove( left( a,B,[x,a,b,a,b,c])).
B = b ;
B = b ;
false.

6 ?- prove( left( b,C,[x,a,b,a,b,c])).
C = a ;
C = c ;
false.
```

The **`;`** is the key that we press to request the next solution from Prolog (while the Prolog pauses, awaiting our command).